# Adding a icon to a specific a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to js and I want to learn what I do rather than simply doing it. so this question is for a forum.
I want to add to a colored group, an icon and I have this code

```
<strong>
    <a href="/">
        <span style="color:#B83EE0">
            <strong>USERNAME</strong>
        </span>
    </a>
</strong>
```

and I want to add an icon to it and I want it to be done with js.

I have this code but I'm stuck at the moment because I  don't know how to get the element by color.

```js
$(function () {
  $('a span[style="color:#6eb1d6;"] strong').each(function () {
    var icon = ' here is the icon';
    $()
  })
});
```

I'd like to understand what I do rather than copy paste. Thank you

Comment: So, you want to add an icon image in front of "USERNAME" text. What do you mean by `$('a span[style="color:#6eb1d6;"] strong')`? In JS, why did you select color that is different from your html?

Comment: Hello, I just fast pasted it, i wanted to change there as well but I asked too fast, It can be any of it, it doesn't matter the color. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
Basically, adding an img tag in front of your content in span.

```
$(function() {              

    $('span[style="color:#6eb1d6;"]').each(function() {  
            
        var icon = 'img/icon.jpg';  // your icon image file with right path
        var content = $('span[style="color:#6eb1d6;"]').html();
        $('span[style="color:#6eb1d6;"]').html("<img src='"+icon+"'>"+content);
  
    }); 
});
```